# Javascript dynamicly change DOM using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

PHP code

```
    <?php
    
    ...
    
    //Extract the data that was sent to the server
    $email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $password = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'password', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    
    
     
    
    $findemail = [
    "email" => $email, 
    "password" => $password, 
    ];
    
    $cursor = $collection->findOne($findemail);
    if($cursor){
    if($cursor['email'] == $email and $cursor['password'] == $password){ 

// I Know these two lines don't work but I want to show what I want to do 
       echo "success";
        header('location: cms-view-products.html');
    }

else {
    echo "failed";
    header('location: login.php');
}

}
    
      ?>
```

AND this is my HTML code

```
  <?php include('demo2.php') ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="demo2.php" onsubmit="return false"; method="post">
            Email: <input type="email" name="email" required >
            name: <input type="password" name="password" required >
        <button type='submit' onclick="loadContent()">Load</button>
        </form>
        
        
        
        <div id="ServerContent">
            <p>Dynamically loaded content goes here</p>
        </div>
        
        <script>
            function loadContent(){
                var url = "demo2.php";
                var email = document.getElementsByName('email').value;
                
            
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open("POST", url);

            xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

            xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
                        
            document.getElementById("ServerContent").innerHTML = this.responseData;
            
            }
            else
                    alert("Error communicating with server");
            }

            var data = `JSON.stringify({
            "email": "document.getElementsByName('email').value",
            "name": "document.getElementsByName('name').value"
            })`;

            xhr.send(data);
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I've currently tried to echo the message via JS, the specific element `<p id=" feedback"></p>`, nevertheless it doesn't work. With PHP the process works, nevertheless, I can't redirect users using headers. I've found `$_SESSION` could resolve this issue. However, my question is to use JS to open a pop-up and then redirect the user to x page?

I edited the post since comments advised me about using Ajax and so this is my first attempt. I can always achieve one of the two either redirect the user to x page or show an error massage. but I can't do both.

Also, I don't want to alert the massage, but to change HTML element dynamically.

Thanks guys for your time and comments.

Comment: **Warning!** Never store passwords in plain text! You should only store password hashes generated using [password_hash()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and to verify a password againts a hash, use [password_verify()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php). You should also _never_ sanitize/escape passwords since that can change them, making them considerably weaker and in worse case **make them blank!** I don't see a reason for those `filter_input()`'s at all tbh.

Comment: Thanks for replaying. I will look for that now.

Comment: I would recommend that you learn about Ajax. That allows you to make the request in the background. Then you can redirect if it was success full or show what ever message you want without the page reloading at all.

Comment: You should use "ajax" for this purpose. You can use javascript's native "fetch" function or some package like https://github.com/axios/axios . Prevent submitting via HTML (PHP) and do everything via JS.

Comment: _Side note:_ There's also no reason for that `if($cursor['email'] == $emai ...` since you're actively only fetching the documents that do match those values. That `if`-statement would never evaluate as `false`.